# How to get many elements given a attribute of a XML in T-SQL with XQUERY?

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql, xquery

I would like to know how to get all the elements in  that have the attribute TIPO and thas is equal to "MC"

The XML is:

```
<ROOT>
  <PARAMETERS>
    <USU_LOGIN>yleon</USU_LOGIN>
    <USU_NOMBREPRIMERO>Yerusha</USU_NOMBREPRIMERO>
    <USU_APELLIDOPRIMERO>Leon</USU_APELLIDOPRIMERO>
    <USU_EMAIL>yleon@pt.com.ve</USU_EMAIL>
    <USU_FECHACREACION>201305270</USU_FECHACREACION>
    <USU_CONDITIONS1 TIPO="MC">AND USU_ID=4</USU_CONDITIONS1>
    <USU_CONDITIONS2 TIPO="MC">AND USU_ID=5</USU_CONDITIONS2>
    <USU_CONDITIONS3 TIPO="ZZ">AND USU_ID=9</USU_CONDITIONS3>
  </PARAMETERS>
</ROOT>
```

And the result expected is:

```
AND USU_ID=4
AND USU_ID=5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this :

```
DECLARE @xml XML
SET @xml = '<ROOT>
  <PARAMETERS>
    <USU_LOGIN>yleon</USU_LOGIN>
    <USU_NOMBREPRIMERO>Yerusha</USU_NOMBREPRIMERO>
    <USU_APELLIDOPRIMERO>Leon</USU_APELLIDOPRIMERO>
    <USU_EMAIL>yleon@pt.com.ve</USU_EMAIL>
    <USU_FECHACREACION>201305270</USU_FECHACREACION>
    <USU_CONDITIONS1 TIPO="MC">AND USU_ID=4</USU_CONDITIONS1>
    <USU_CONDITIONS2 TIPO="MC">AND USU_ID=5</USU_CONDITIONS2>
    <USU_CONDITIONS3 TIPO="ZZ">AND USU_ID=9</USU_CONDITIONS3>
  </PARAMETERS>
</ROOT>'


-- RESULTS
SELECT txt = T.Item.value('data(.)', 'varchar(255)')
FROM   @xml.nodes('//PARAMETERS/*') AS T(Item)
WHERE T.Item.value('data(@TIPO)', 'varchar(255)')='MC'


-- output
AND USU_ID=4
AND USU_ID=5
```

Comment: It functions perfectly! Thx u very much.. I'm very glad!

Answer (score 0):

Which language?

I think it would be ideal to have all nodes with the same name.

Ex. `USU_CONDTITIONS`

If you use XPath, the code is similar to

```
count(//USU_CONDITIONS[contains(@TIPO,'MC')])
```

Now, if you can not to change the node, you need to count node by node separately.